# Save excel file received from the server on client machine

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html, spring-mvc

I have an link ("a" element) that sends a post request to the server. The server responds with an excel file that I want to download in the client side.

SERVER CODE:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/applicabilityExcel", method=POST)
@ResponseBody
public void getApplicability(@RequestParam("id") String reportId, HttpServletResponse response, HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException{
    int id = Integer.valueOf(reportId);
    Report report = repository.getReport(id);
    InputStream is = new ExcelWriter().getConformityMatrix(report);
    response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
    org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(is, response.getOutputStream());
    response.flushBuffer();     
}
```

CLIENT CODE:

```
<a class="appMatrix" href="<c:out value="${report.id}" />"> App</a>
$(".appMatrix").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post( "/applicabilityExcel",
            {id:$(this).attr("href")},
            function(data){
                console.log(data);
                //I have the file in data variable and I need now to stock it in the client machine (open dialog window, save it directly...)
            });
});
```

My problem is I don't know what to do to stock this file in client machine ("download it").

I tried to donwload the file as text/base64, put it on href of "a" element and call click() but it doesn't work for me.

All responses and suggestions are welcome.

Comment: simplest would be to post form to same url ...then would force download automatically

Comment: jQuery has issue processing binary data at `$.ajax()`. What is `data` within `$.post()` success callback?

Comment: @guest271314 `data` is the server response (`org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(is, response.getOutputStream());`). It contains inputstream of an excel file

Comment: Have you tried using `XMLHttpRequest()` with `.responseType` set to `"blob"`, or `fetch()`, `Response.blob()`?

Comment: @charlietfl, With a form it works but the file name is set to a default file name. Do you have an idea about how can I set the file name?
The javaScript code is :

    `$('<input name="id" />').attr('type', 'hidden')
        .attr('value',$(this).attr("href"))
        .appendTo('#formD');
    $('#formD').submit();`

Comment: I actually set the file name by adding response header on the server side : 

`response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename="+fileName);`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this here , works for me

```
$scope.exportExcel = function(){
    var self = this;
    var url = //yourapi;
    $http.get(url, { responseType: "arraybuffer" }).then(
        function (result) {
            var blob = new Blob([result.data], { type: 'application/vnd.ms-excel' });
            var a = document.createElement('a');
            var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            a.href = url;
            a.download = ""//yourfilename
            a.target = '_blank';
            document.body.appendChild(a);
            a.click();;
        });
};
```

Comment: note that `download` not supported in some legacy browsers

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I found using form post like proposed in  @charlietfl comment is the simplest as he mentioned .